# html tags decoded as special characters in column

Tags: html, teradata

The html characters from UI is escaped and stored as special character in the Teradata DB.

Am looking for a function in Teradata which is similar to `dbms_xmlgen.convert` or `UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE` in oracle.

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('It&#39; ') FROM DUAL
```

In oracle would give
`It'` .

Any Teradata equivalent function to achieve this?

Comment: SELECT  UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('It&#39; ')  FROM DUAL

Comment: As far as I know, Teradata doesn't have html encoding and decoding functions, you'd have to write your own.

Comment: @Alterego, Which version of teradata database you are using?

Comment: this is the version - Teradata 15.10